# Laravel event updated makes SQL crash

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a `ActionLogTrait` trait which looks like the following;

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

trait ActionLogTrait
{
    public static function bootActionLogTrait()
    {
        self::updated(function($model){
            $model->update([
                'updated_by' => auth()->user()->id,
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

I've added this trait to my `Posts`-model.

But when i perform an update on this `Posts`-model, from a `PostController` with `$post->update(['name' => $request->name]);`, then my SQL stops doing things for a few minutes. Like it's in a loop or something. The update works fine without using the trait.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stuck in a infinite loop because you are updating a model after the update event happens, therefore triggering another update event, that updates the model again and so on...

Comment: Omg, your absolutely right. How can i overcome this? Any ideas?

Comment: You should update the updated_by field when ever the post is updated in the controller. Not as a trait that is really an observer. The other option would be to have an intermediary table that holds the post update history, in which case you could use an observer to update that table.

Comment: Fixed it with a little check `if ($model->updated_by !== auth()->user()->id) { }`